# middleware to send authorization token with all outbound requests in node js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a Express `api` which sends the request to other api's to get the information.Token is a `jwt` which expires every minute. So technically I have to attach new tokens in the header for each outbound request.  Is there any way to attach authorization token in headers of all outbound requests.

route.js file:

```
'use strict';
  router.get('/api/request', function (req, res) {
     var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
     var client = new Client();


     client.post("http:/localhost:3000/client", args, function (data, response) {
         console.log(response.status);
      });

  });

  server.use(router);
};
```

This is a sample post request from one of the module made to other service from the api. Similar to this there are serveral other requests. I want to add the authorization token in the header for all the requests made from this api.

Comment: token is a jwt which expires every minute. so technically I have to attach new tokens in the header for each outbound request.

Comment: Can You add some which tried so far?

Comment: Updated with a sample code. currently lets say there is a module which gives a random string when called. Using that I want to set the header for all outbound requests without modifying the request code in every module.

Comment: Create common service, generate token and make all HTTP calls from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Creat One entry point(Service) for all API call and validate there. If the token has created before 45 seconds use same else regenerate new and use.

```
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const HttpService = (method, url, args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var client = new Client();
        if (method == 'POST') {
            client.post(url, args, function (data, response) {
                // If err  reject(err)
                resolve(response);
            });
        }
        // Same for get and other
    });
}

let basetoken, tokenExpire = Date.now() + 1000 * 45;
const getToken = async () => {
    // Check token is generated before 45 Seconds or not
    if (!basetoken || tokenExpire < Date.now()) { 
        basetoken = await HttpService('POST', 'Token URl', 'SomeData');
        tokenExpire = Date.now() + 1000 * 45; // Token validity you can change this to some value
    }
    return basetoken;
}

const HttpPost = async (url, data) => {
    const token = await getToken();
    data.headers = {Token : token};
    const data = await HttpService('POST', url, data);
    return data;
}

module.exports ={ HttpPost }
```

Comment: I am looking for a middleware which should be able to handle this scenario, Similar to the way we intercept inbound requests for token validation or use a proxy which can intercept all outbound requests- attach a header and let it go because we don't want to make changes in any of the request methods that are in the project.

Comment: It's Middleware between your controller and HTTP call. You just have to call HttpPost and pass URL and Body Params, No need to add token and verify that.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am very new to node.js. This is not exactly what we want but sure this work around can buy me a couple of days for research. How can we inject the token generated into header of the post request in your code.

Comment: As for as the solution I am looking for is like "public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)" in java